# Unexpected element when calling getElementByTagName

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I'm new to javascript and don't understand why I get a function after my tags as output when I'm looping in a collection when I call getElementByTagName();

I'm a noob in English so here is a snippet to figure you out what's my question and my issue.

```js
function div1ParaElems() {
            const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
            const div1Paras = div1.getElementsByTagName("div");
            const num = div1Paras.length;
            alert(`There are ${num} paragraph in #div1`);
            let out = document.getElementById("output");
            for (let i in div1Paras){
                out.innerHTML += div1Paras[i] + "<br>";
        div1Paras[i].addEventListener("click",alertMe);
            }
        }
        function alertMe(e){
            alert(e.target.innerHTML);
        }
```

```css
*{
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .flexTest{
            display: flex;
            flex: auto;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-items: flex-start;
            /*justify-content: space-around;*/
            /*justify-content: space-between;*/
            border:1px solid #D2D2D2;
            background-color: burlywood;
        }
        .flexTest div{
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            padding:10px;
            margin:10px;
            display: flex;
            flex: content;
            border:1px solid #D2D2D2;
        }
```

```html
<body onLoad="div1ParaElems()">
    <div id="div1" class="flexTest">
        <div>
            Tatactic - Nicolas 1
        </div>
        <div>
            Tatactic - Nicolas 2
        </div>
        <div>
            Tatactic - Nicolas 3
        </div>
        <div>
            Tatactic - Nicolas 4
        </div>
        <div>
            Tatactic - Nicolas 5
        </div>
        <div>
            Tatactic - Nicolas 6
        </div>
        <div>
            Tatactic - Nicolas 7
        </div>
        <div>
            Tatactic - Nicolas 8
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Why do I get `function item() { [native code] }` at the end of my output even if it's not a div element???

Thank you in advance for your time and your patience!

Output contains 9 elements and not 8 as expected.

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
function item() { [native code] }
```

Comment: Running your snippet, I am only seeing [object HTMLDivElement] 3 times before it throws "Error: "Uncaught TypeError: div1Paras[i].addEventListener is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `for..in`, which treats `div1Paras` as an object, iterating over its properties (including `length`, the `item` method, etc). You probably want to use `for..of` instead.

```
for (let div of div1Paras) {
  out.innerHTML += div + "<br>";
  div.addEventListener("click", alertMe);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that there was a for...of statement in javascript!!!
Thank you again!!!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of